# Windows 10 server ssh tunnel to Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: windows, networking, ssh

**source:** Windows 10 Server (local port 8081)

**destination:** Ubuntu

**ssh tunnel:** Putty

`Windows10 server------->ssh tunnel--------->Ubuntu`

I have the ssh tunnel up between the source and destination

**destination** netstat:

`tcp        0      0 192.168.1.106:ssh       asdasd.asd.asd:62040 ESTABLISHED`

**source** is binding on port 8081:

```
C:\Users\asd\Desktop>netstat -a | find /N "8081"
[29]  TCP    127.0.0.1:8081         asd_asd:0          LISTENING
```

Problem is, when I set the browser or system proxy to `localhost:8081` on the **source** side nothing works. On the **destination** I ran a tcpdump matching against dest port 8081 to see if the packet comes out of the tunnel but looks like it doesn't:

```
asd@asdasd:/var/log$ sudo tcpdump dst port 8081
Password:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

I'm trying telnet on the **source** side to trigger the tcpdump:

`C:\Users\asd\Desktop>telnet 127.0.0.1 8081`

On the **destination** side I got the following enabled under sshd_config:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
```

On the **source** side I have MS Defender off, checked the router logs nothing. It almost feels like the packets never get into the tunnel. Any idea how to troubleshoot futher?